# how extension can read the registry

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, registry

i want to read window registry value from extension's javascript. For Internet Explorer we can use ActiveXObject.But dont know how to read registry in Firefox case.

Please do help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nsIWindowsRegKey` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowsRegKey) is your friend here. 
[Accessing the Windows Registry Using XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessing_the_Windows_Registry_Using_XPCOM) has some examples, for example:

```js
var wrk = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/windows-registry-key;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowsRegKey);
wrk.open(wrk.ROOT_KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
         "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion",
         wrk.ACCESS_READ);
var id = wrk.readStringValue("ProductId");
wrk.close();
```

Comment: Thats fine. i've another doubt. Is future Firefox supporting this XPCOM component ?

Comment: Yes, why not? It has been supported since Firefox 1.5. Btw, feel free to accept the answer if it helped: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask